# Show Google pie charts on click at text or image?

Tags: javascript, php, google-pie-chart

I did not manage to set up a link where an onClick() - action would generate a Goolge pie chart. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/) is an example via JSFiddle.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Work',     11],
      ['Eat',      2],
      ['Commute',  2],
      ['Watch TV', 2],
      ['Sleep',    7]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
```

I would like to have a clickable text or string such that after a click a small window or pop-up window appears with the chart in it. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not a php question, but javascript. If you want to attach an onclick event in your HTML use on click event like so: onclick="drawChart()"

Comment: Thanks, but this is not working for me. I tried this one       '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>       
           <p onclick="drawChart()">
            Hello World!
           </p>' but no success!

Comment: Its hard to tell what the problem is not seeing all the code. Post all parts of the code

Comment: Hi @K.I , the above code is runable in JSFiddle. In my previous comment i replaced the <div> tag with the <p> tag like so:  <p onclick="drawChart()"> Hello World! </p>'. Now the code is still runable, but no Chart appears nor the 'Hello World' is clickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is full code that works:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     11],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'My Daily Activities'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      function your_function(){
        if (document.getElementById('piechart').style.display==='none') 
        {  
            document.getElementById('piechart').style.display='block';
        }
        else
        {
            document.getElementById('piechart').style.display='none';
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;" ></div>
    <p onclick="your_function();" >Click Me</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, K.I. It works now. I wonder if there is a chance to have the piechart poping up in a new smaller sized window?

Comment: No problem. And yes it is possible, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/kjrtr/1/

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but how would one include this Javascript into a php or html script? I am asking, because I can not see the connection between the html scrlpt and the jquery function in your example.

Comment: You can include this line in your html head element: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>